# Stored procedure throws error for Guids in Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, guid

I have an entity that has `GuidId` as primary key of type `Guid`. I am trying to call a stored procedure that has the GuidId as Sql Parameter, but I get this error

`Incorrect syntax near '@Id'.`

```
CreateStoredProcedure("dbo.MyStoredProc",
         param => new
         {
             Id = param.String()
         },
        body:
        @"DECLARE @GuidId uniqueidentifier = convert(uniqueidentifier, @Id)
        ...");

repository.ExecuteQuery("EXEC MyStoredProc @Id", 
                        new SqlParameter("@Id", entity.GuidId.ToString()));

public void ExecuteQuery(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);
    }
```

I guess that there is something wrong with the passing Guids to SQL, that's why I tried to pass it as string and then convert it. The stored procedure works if executed in Sql, but what is wrong here?

Comment: I hope your guid as a primary key is not also the clustered index. You will exceed 99% fragmentation with as few as a thousand rows. A different column is a better choice for the clustered index or you have to constantly keep defragmenting your clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

If your `GuidId PK` is of Guid type, you have an error passing the parameter `entity.GuidId.ToString()`. You should declare `GuidId` as string an keep the other thing the same, or not convert the parameter toString.